# how to restrict user to "home page" when user copy paste link.

Tags: java, jsp

how to restrict user to "homePage" when the user is copying and pasting the link from one browser to other browser...
ie

when user copying link in my project "localhost:8080/MyJavaProjectV1.0/Admin_GetTokenId.jsp"   from Internet Explorer

and

pasting it in chrome..i want the user to be restricted to homepage..

Comment: Homepage would be localhost:8080?

Comment: How are verifying if the user is loggedin?

Comment: homepage is localhost:8080/MyJavaProjectV1.0/

Comment: sorry if im unable to convey my question properly....i hav posted the solution i made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every jsp page after the user was logged in, I am saving the username in a session and  I am displaying username in every page, like...

```
hai  <%= ss.getAttribute("username")%>
```

now I have used that username session and checking if username is null or empty..
if its null(ie the link is copied and pasted to other browser..) then im redirecting to login page

```
if(ss.getAttribute("username")==null || ss.getAttribute("username")=="")
{
    response.sendRedirect("loginpage.jsp");
}
```

Comment: sorry if im unable to convey my question properly

Answer (score 1):

Add a servlet filter that filters each request to home page and checks if request is authenticated to be serve - serve, restrict otherwise

---

**Also See**

- [Writing an authorization filter for my web app(JSF 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662367/writing-an-authorization-filter-for-my-web-appjsf-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any app server with login configured for authentication, simply secure all the URL patterns except `Login` page in your `web.xml` file. **If the user tries the access any URL other than 'Login' page(or more unsecured URLs) without authentication, `Login` page will be presented by default.**. Your config would look like below:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Sample Security Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role><role-name>admin</role-name></security-role>
<security-role><role-name>user</role-name></security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
        <!-- Mention your URL pattern here for admin access check>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>  
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>User</web-resource-name>
        <!-- Mention your URL pattern here for standard user access check>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

If you are not using any app server, and using webserver such as `apache` to front-end your application, use security plugins of apache with your authentication mechanism e.g. `Siteminder` gels with `Apache` very well.

If you none of the above is applicable, configure a request filter, check the user, and redirect to the Login page, if user is not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear whether there is any sort of authentication. 
Assuming that this doesn't have to do with authentication one solution is to look at an http header called referrer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer  the referrer header carries information about which page was the user previously on.

You can create a servlet filter which checks the referrer. on access to any article check the referrer header, if its any page or website that is not your homepage or if referrer is blank you will forward the user to the homepage, otherwise send the user to the page he requested.