# Java: Using filter (user logged/user not logged)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, filter, servlet-filters

I need to write a code, that will be redirecting to different *.jsp sites depending on whether user is logged on or not logged on. I found a hint, that I can use filter to do it and I need to use doFilter or/along with init methods. Any ideas?

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    }
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic sample...but let's suppose that the login proces set in session an attribute called "user"
in the doFilter method you can do something like this

```
if( request.getSession().getAttribute("user") == null )
{
//User not logged...redirect
}
else
{
//Normal filter execution
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`init()` method will be called on Filter's initialization and `doFilter()` will be called when a request is made and `Filter` is mapped to filter those request

---

Related:

- [How to implement role-based access control Java/MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946119/how-to-implement-role-based-access-control-java-mysql)
- [Writing an authorization filter for my web app(JSF 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662367/writing-an-authorization-filter-for-my-web-appjsf-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

For an example, see [Filters Tutorial](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/articles/j2ee/filters.html), particularly the section titled Authentication with Filters. (There's a typo that actually makes this say "Authentication with Filers" but that is the section I am referring to...obviously it is supposed to say filters :)