# JSF2 - Flexible way on restrict access on certain xhtml pages, apply simple logic on access

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Hi I am actually trying to get tips or ideas on a very specific problem. The technology context is 
java web app with JSF 2.1 .

So I have a simple java ee app powered by JSF 2.1. The structure is the following

```
\webapp
   \WEB-INF
      \templates 
       header.xhtml
       menu.xhtml
      web.xml 
   \secured 
      \operation1
       op1.xhtml
     \operation2
       op2.xhtml
     \operation3
      op3.xhtml 
    userhome.xhtml
  login.xhtml
```

I have one `@WebFilter` that restricts the access to `/secured/*` in case the 'user' bean is not set (Actually a Session Scoped Bean).

At the same time upon login, I create a dynamic Menu depending on the user credential. this menu (MenuItems) point to one or more operations (xhtml pages).

So far so good, the user logins, the menu is dynamic, links are being generated and upon clicking he/she can navigate to whatever operations he/she is supposed to do.

My problem is that I can not decide on an elegant way on  restricting access to the absolute url of these pages . If user1 is 'authorized' to execute operation1 but not operation2 or operation3, currently I can not find the most elegant way on checking his session state and applying a generic rule (navigation rule?), if the actual web user, writes on the url bar the absolute path of the operation.

'/secured/operation1/op2.xhtml'

What is the most JSF2 compatible way on achieve that kind of requirement?

I have tried the preRenderView on each separate `opxx.xhtml` page , unfortunately it did not work + i dont like repeating it on each operation

Many thanks for your tips.

Comment: Did you considered writing [a filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662367/writing-an-authorization-filter-for-my-web-appjsf-2-0) for that? That way you can restrict url's in a pattern-based way.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Yes I have considered the Filter solution but I am a bit puzzled regarding it's ugly-ness in terms of handling all the relevant or potential urls. For example I should parse the request url, search for the /operation folder (if I follow this convention) and the have some sort of mapping with strings that are going to indicate that e.g op1.xhtml which maps to Operation.ONE is valid for user1 etc. I am trying to find a more generic way on actually making this 'application' level custom authorization , a concrete thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security in web applications is a more advanced topic. Basically you have two ways:

- Container based: This means your servlet container like Tomcat does the job for you (recommended)
- Application based: You have to do the job on your own

How to setup container based security is explained in detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html). To summarize it, you have to implement a simple form (no JSF form!) with a specific action and specific ids for the username and password field. Afterwards you can easily restrict access to specific URL patterns using your web.xml file. In the web.xml file you restrict access to certain URL patterns for certain user roles. The mapping from usernames to user roles is done by a security realm. How to setup a security realm is desribed e.g. for Tomcat [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Standard_Realm_Implementations).

If you want to implement security on your own, you have to implement a ServletFilter that inspects all requested URLs and either forwards users that are not logged in to your login form or passes the request through if the user is authorized. If the user is not authorized to see the page, you will have to forward the user to your error page. As CDI injection does not work for ServletFilter, you will have to lookup the bean that stores the information about your user (logged in, rights) from the HttpSession.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. It seems that there is no elegant solution on that particular problem. My two options are. 1. Custom Filter with request url processing and link to my 'custom' role based mechanism . 2. Experiment with the @PreRenderEvent on each JSF xhtml, maybe I am placing the tag in the incorrect place and the event listener is not triggered. Thanks